# Yii2: Saving data to unsafe attribute?

Tags: php, yii2

I have set up one attribute in my model as `'!pagrawal_serial_number'` as `integer` and in my controller my code I am using some condition to assign  a value to this attribute, but it is not getting saved.

even if I am using this simple code, it is not working, that is no data is saved in this field.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
       $model->pagrawal_serial_number = 39;
       $model->save();
 ....
```

**Note:** In my another model and controller, I have set up similar rule, which is working fine.

I tried to do everything but nothing seems to work, what else I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution partly.

I used this code to find any validation error:

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    $model->pagrawal_serial_number = 39;
} else {   
    $errors = $model->errors;
    var_dump($errors);exit;
}
```

This gave me an error `appointment_date is not formatted correctly`
I have a rule set up for appointment date in my model like this:

```
[['appointment_date'], 'date','format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i a'],
```

I commented out this `appointment_date` rule and I am now able to save the data to unsafe attribute as referred in the question.

> Only thing I wonder is how I am able to save the same in the first
>   instance and the validation fails on the second instance?

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate more. There may be errors onSave() beforeSave() or afterSave() of your models. We could not pinpoint the line number from which the error is originating if you provide incomplete details. Thanks.